# Dodecahedron (or any platonic solids) uniform rotations, so that the vertices do not overlap any of the previous rotations

Tags: rotation

How to rotate an object, so that its vertices never overlap with any of the other rotations? With a predefined number of rotations.

Idea:
It can be achieved with relaxation. (Idea comes from Greg Turk's paper: Generating Textures on Arbitrary Surfaces Using Reaction-Diffusion)

Steps:

1. Generate x dodecahedrons or any object symmetric to its centre
   point.
2. These objects should be identical in position, orientation
   and size. (so we can create an easy relation between vertices =>
   ones that overlap at the beginning are related)
3. Create a function that calculates the distance between the related points.
4. Maximize the average distance between related points. (every point has x-1
   related points)

Problems:
This is not a simple relaxation problem with points. Here, due to the dodecahedron constraint, I cannot just translate around. Rotation matrixes/quaternions are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution with Brute force
**Summary**:
*Rotate randomly until desired average distance is achieved*.
**Explanation**:
*Every dodecahedron is rotated until it's vertices do not overlap any vertices of the other dodecahedrons.
Then average distance is calculated and checked against the best (minimal) so far. Save all vertex positions, and the rotation quaternion, that will turn the base dodecahedron into the rotated one.*

```
float minThreshold <- user defined
int iterationThreshold <- user defined
float minAveDistance = Infinity;


while (minAveDistance > minThreshold || maxIteration > iterationThreshold) {
    Foreach (dodecahedron) { // except the first one, that can stay as is
// rotate randomly until there are no overlapping positions with the other dodecahedrons
        while (checkOverlappingWithOtherDodecahedrons(dodecahedron)) {
            rotateRandomly(dodecahedron);
        }
    }
    float aveDistance = CalculateAverageDistanceBetweenAllPointsOfDodecahedrons();
    if (aveDistance < minAveDistance) {
        minAveDistance = aveDistance;
        SaveAllPositions(); // e.g.: to a file
        SaveAllRotationQuaternionsFromStartOrientation(); // e.g.: to a file
    }
}
```